# Are there any algorithms for removing lighting from a video?

Tags: video, video-processing, lighting

Are there any algorithms for removing lighting from video? I have a video in which some objects are too strongly lit. How might I remove lighting from that objects without corrupting the entire video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the most straight forward approach will be something like this:

```
for each frame in video
    convert to HSL
    select connected pixels which have luminance above a certain threshold
    convert those areas that are "large" to regions
    expand regions or soften the region (soft mask, Gaussian blur)
    mask original image to that area
    apply either brightness/contrast or histogram equalize on that area
    overlay back onto original image
```